# Matching fuzzy strings

Tags: database, string, postgresql, matching, fuzzy

I have two tables that I need to merge together in PostgreSQL, on the common variable "company name."  Unfortunately many of the company names don't match exactly (i.e. MICROSOFT in one table, MICROSFT in the other).  I've tried removing common words from both columns such as "corporation" or "inc" or "ltd" in order to try to standardize names across both tables, but I'm having trouble thinking of additional strategies.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Also, if necessary I can do this in R.

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered the fuzzystrmatch module? You can use `soundex`, `difference`, `levenshtein`, `metaphone` and `dmetaphone`, or a combination.

[fuzzystrmatch documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)

```
SELECT something
FROM somewhere
WHERE levenshtein(item1, item2) < Carefully_Selected_Threshold
```

For example the levenshtein distance from **MICROSOFT** to **MICROSFT** is one (1).

```
levenshtein(dmetaphone('MICROSOFT'), dmetaphone('MICROSFT')
```

The above returns zero (0). Combining levenshtein and dmetaphone could help you match lots of misspellings.

Comment: Also consider pg_trgm , I`ve had much success with it in deduplication scenarios.